# Error: Access Denied: (403) Forbidden?

Tags: asp.net

what is the solution of this type error

reply soon

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 3):

Follow these links it will help you.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html

http://403forbiddenerror.org/

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you dont have appropriate permission to access the resource.

Configure your IIS to enable anonymous/Windows authentication and see if that works. If not then you should give more details about the configuration and your application.